# Group whose maximal subgroups are normal

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group(not necessary finite) such that every maximal subgroup of $G$ is normal. Then Why $G^{\prime} \leq \Phi(G)$?

Comment: What is $\Phi(G)$ supposed to mean?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom That's standard notation for the Frattini subgroup.

Comment: What is $G'$?  The derived group?

Comment: @DerekHolt okay, thank you.

Comment: If every maximal subgroup is normal then it must have prime index, and the result follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H$ be a maximal subgroup of $G$.  Since $H$ is normal in $G$, the quotient $G/H$ has a group structure, whose subgroups are in bijection with the subgroups of $G$ containing $H$.  By the maximality of $H$ in $G$, the group $G/H$ has no nontrivial proper subgroups.  The only way this can happen is if $G/H$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ for a prime number $p$.

In particular, $G/H$ is abelian.  The derived group $G'$ has the property that it is normal in $G$, and is contained in every normal subgroup $N$ for which $G/N$ is abelian.

This shows that $G'$ is contained in every maximal subgroup of $G$.